Logit model not predicting any values < 0 despite class imbalance
I am building a logistic regression model to identify potential channelling factors that predict whether a patient will initiate of one of two antidiabetic drug classes at a specific stage in their disease. My dataset is highly imbalanced, with 97.5% (n = 15292) of patients initiating class B and only 2.5% (n = 394) initiating class A.
logit_model <- glm(class_A ~ centered_age + female + creat*days_to_first_fill + 
                             cause + centered_bmi + dgf + LiverDisease + 
                             fill_era, 
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                      data = dt)

After fitting the logistic regression model and converting the predicted log odds to probabilities using the expit function, I observed that none of the predicted probabilities are below 0.5 (i.e., none of the log odds are less than 0). The range of predicted probabilities is also narrow, with the vast majority of patients having a probability around 50%.
summary(dt$pred_prob)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.5002  0.5014  0.5029  0.5063  0.5054  0.6724

Given the imbalanced nature of the data, I expected the predicted probabilities to reflect the observed class distribution, with a majority of probabilities below 0.5 for the insulin initiation class. However, the model seems to be assigning probabilities around 0.5 for most patients, indicating poor discrimination between the two classes. It almost feels like the fitted values from the model are probabilities instead of log odds.
summary(logit_model$fitted.values)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0007501 0.0057085 0.0115473 0.0251822 0.0214111 0.7189886 

For reference here is my model output:
Coefficients:
                                                                Estimate  Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                  -5.56850007  0.17583038 -31.670 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
centered_age                                                  0.00007974  0.00480505   0.017             0.986759    
femaleFemale                                                  0.04008379  0.11260580   0.356             0.721866    
creat                                                        -0.08360708  0.03568126  -2.343             0.019121 *  
days_to_first_fill                                            0.01944154  0.00120843  16.088 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
causeGlomerular Nephritis                                     1.51663048  0.19201817   7.898  0.00000000000000283 ***
causeHypertensive Nephrosclerosis                             1.30805147  0.14719779   8.886 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
causeOther                                                    1.08617629  0.14338594   7.575  0.00000000000003586 ***
centered_bmi                                                 -0.02047943  0.01071770  -1.911             0.056030 .  
dgfDelayed Graft Function                                    -0.54979993  0.14787923  -3.718             0.000201 ***
LiverDiseaseModerate to Severe Liver Disease                 -0.43294637  0.24443026  -1.771             0.076520 .  
fill_eraFirst fill 2013-2020                                  1.10826539  0.14895235   7.440  0.00000000000010038 ***
centered_mrcreat:days_to_first_fill                           0.00101324  0.00036170   2.801             0.005089 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3679.1  on 15645  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2975.4  on 15633  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3001.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7

Has anyone experienced anything like this before? I'm unsure how to address this.

"It almost feels like the fitted values from the model are probabilities instead of log odds". They are probabilities.

Completely misread the documentation. Thank you!
